# In leaflet how to display both tooltip and image on marker mouseover?

Tags: javascript, image, leaflet

All my leaflet markers have associated text information and a subset of these markers have an associated image. Currently I am using the bindTootip() method to show the text on mouseover.

Is it possible to embed the image in the Tooltip?  Or is there a better way to achieve both text and image presentation on mouseover?

Answer (score 1):

found the answer at: https://plnkr.co/edit/QxqvzaIgmONlCo0jirHy?p=preview&preview

simply add the image link to the text, e.g.

```
.bindTooltip(my_text_info  + '<br>' + "<img src='" + img_url + "'/>");
```